# Using commas and semicolons in C++ threads

Tags: c++, syntax, comma-operator

I was reading on [cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com) and encountered this bit of code:

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits, 1), t2(waits, 2), t3(waits, 3), t4(signals);
    t1.join(); t2.join(), t3.join(), t4.join();
}
```

I was wondering if the last line was a typo.

Shouldn't it be this:

```
    int main()
    {
        std::thread t1(waits, 1), t2(waits, 2), t3(waits, 3), t4(signals);
        t1.join(), t2.join(), t3.join(), t4.join();
    }
```

Or does it make no difference?

Comment: The original programmer must have been embroiled in a *"line-saving-contest"*.  While this isn't as bad as some "string it together with commas", as the line of joins closely tracks the thread declarations above, it's not the best for readability.

Answer (score 4):

It makes no difference. Both the comma operator and the semi-colon impose sequencing, the only difference is in how the results of each expression are handled. Since `join` has a `void` return type, even that tiny difference doesn't really matter. Either way, you'd `join` each thread, in order, from left to right.

Personally, I'd have used semicolons exclusively, because the comma operator (on the rare occasions it's used outside of a `for` loop increment step) implies the return values matter, but `join` being `void` return type makes that feature of the comma operator meaningless; `t1.join(); t2.join(); t3.join(); t4.join();` would be equally correct, and remove any doubt about whether something fishy was going on with the comma operator.

Comment: Cppreference fixed